# Magento: Input type "text" not found in the input types list

Tags: magento

When I try to create new product attributes from Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes, it's showing the error "Input type "text" not found in the input types list". "Error while saving product Attribute."

It happens for any attribute type; text, dropdown, multiselect, etc...

There are also some errors in the system.log:

```
ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Zend_Validate_InArray::setHaystack() must be of the type array, null given, called in lib/Zend/Validate/InArray.php on line 96 and defined in lib/Zend/Validate/InArray.php on line 122
ERR (3): Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given  in lib/Zend/Validate/InArray.php on line 196
```

Comment: No idea why this was down-voted. I encountered this exact same issue for this exact same reason. If I hadn't found this SO question I could have spent hours trying to determine the cause and fix it.

Comment: @Eric you should post your own answer

Answer (score 3):

You may have an entry in the `core_config_data` table for `path="general"`. The definition of `general/validator_data/input_types` comes from `app/code/core/Mage/Eav/etc/config.xml` but the database config entry will override it.

Here is a query to find it: `SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path="general";`

Here is a query to remove (fix) it: `DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path="general";`

The issue is that this code is returning a null value for `$haystack` and so you will get an error `Input type "%value%" not found in the input types list.` It will happen for any input type.

```
$helper = Mage::helper('eav');
$haystack = $helper->getInputTypesValidatorData();

const XML_PATH_VALIDATOR_DATA_INPUT_TYPES = 'general/validator_data/input_types';

public function getInputTypesValidatorData()
{
    return Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_VALIDATOR_DATA_INPUT_TYPES);
}
```

That is because `Mage::getStoreConfig('general/validator_data/input_types');` is returning null. It's happening because this "general" row in the `core_config_data` is overriding the entire definition from the XML.

Answer (score 1):

GO to `core_congif_data` table of your database and delete the entry of path general. Try this solution it will working for sure